# How to stretch inline flexbox container to the size of it's content when min-width/flex-basis is applied?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have next document structure. There is a container which holds 3 rows each of which holds 3 columns.
I want to make all columns except first one to be of a fixed size. The first column should stretch to all available space but never be less than 300px. When there is no space left for the columns on the screen they should expand the row they exist in. To accomplish this I try to use display: **inline-flex** but it's only working if I set a fixed size for my first column using a **width** property. But if I'm setting **min-width** or **flex-basis** to actually benefit from **flex-grow** I'm not getting the desired stretch of a row. How can I accomplish same behavior I have inside my snippet right now but with correct row stretch to the size of its children columns?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.row {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: #a4ff00;
}

.col {
    flex-basis: 200px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.col:first-of-type {
    min-width: 500px;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/lulatoquno/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Try using dipslay flex on the row element. I'm not sure if this is the exact way you want it but I got this as a result:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex; 
  flex-warp: wrap;
  flex-direction: column; 
}

.row {
  background-color: #a4ff00;
  display: flex; 
  width: 100%
}

.col {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 200px;
}
.col:first-of-type{ min-width: 300px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
    <div class="col">BoxBoxBoxBoxBoxBox BoxBoxBox</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you are creating a row layout with a filling content.

Comment: No, that's not a result I wanted to get, try to make the window smaller than your content so the scroll appear and you will see this result http://take.ms/9IUbx